# Sqlite query max and where clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table have 3 fields, i want to get the most repeated ticket_id i have inside, this query works but i need to add a where clause on "is_winner", any help? thanks

```
 ID   TICKET_ID   IS_WINNER
 1    2           1
 2    3           1
 3    2           1
 4    3           0
 5    2           1
 6    2           0
 7    3           0
 8    2           1
 9    2           0


 select query1.* FROM (Select ticket_id, Count(*)  As order_count 
 FROM ticket_log  
 GROUP BY ticket_log.ticket_id) query1,(Select Max(query2.order_count) As highest_count 
 FROM (Select ticket_id, Count(*) As order_count 
 FROM ticket_log 
 GROUP BY ticket_log.ticket_id) query2) query3 where query1.order_count = query3.highest_count
```

Comment: What do you pretend? One row with winner? Get a list of winner tickets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add WHERE clauses:

```
SELECT query1.* FROM (Select ticket_id, Count(*)  As order_count 
FROM ticket_log WHERE is_winner = 1
GROUP BY ticket_log.ticket_id) query1,(Select Max(query2.order_count) As highest_count 
FROM (Select ticket_id, Count(*) As order_count 
FROM ticket_log WHERE is_winner = 1
GROUP BY ticket_log.ticket_id) query2) query3 where query1.order_count = query3.highest_count
```

(edited because I noticed you need *all* winners)

Comment: Tried your solution before before, but i was missing second where clause. It works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ticket_id, COUNT() AS wins
FROM ticket_log
WHERE is_winner=1
GROUP BY ticket_id
ORDER BY wins DESC;
```

Is this?